# What is the different between ProtectedBrowserStorage vs ProtectedLocalStorage in blazor dotnet 6?

Tags: blazor-server-side

Nothing problem I just want to know the different when the best to use either one of them

Nothing problem I just want to know the different when the best to use either one of them

Comment: I think one uses cookies while the other uses the localstorage